# hh:mm duration format only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets to collect some data I need a cell to only allow a duration hh:mm input.

Here is the formula data validation I have right now

```
=regexmatch(text(E11,"hh:mm"), "[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$")
```

The only thing this is not doing for me is not allowing whole number responses (i.e. 1,3,5..). These values break some formulas that I have as 7 = 168 hours in duration. What can I do to limit only to hh:mm format entry?

I am willing to use a script if this is what is needed.

Comment: Datetime is internally a number so regex validation based on a text representation isn't going to work. Instead require the value to be less than 1 (i.e. 00:00-23:59).

Comment: It makes sense to me that 7shoild not work but it does. I am going to try the maximum option.

Answer (score 1):

```
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(E11),"\d{1,2}:[0-5]\d?")
```

- TO_TEXT gets display values instead of number.
- `\d{1,2}` adds a condition for a 1 to 2 digit number.

Comment: Man, this worked like a charm. This has pushed me to increase my REGEX knowledge. Do you have any resources to learn?